# In Django admin, the "view on site" link has "https://" in it twice, making the link unuseable

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model, which has a `get_absolute_url` method defined as follow :

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('shop__restaurant_listing', kwargs={'slug': self.slug, })
```

The reverse portion correctly returns `/varieties/grenaille`.

However, in the Django admin, when I view an instance of the model, the "View on site" link is formatted with "https://" twice. So the link is something like `https://https//www.potato.com/varieties/grenaille/`.

I had a look at the Django code, and found this line in `django.contrib.admin.templates.admin.change_form.html` :

```
{% if has_absolute_url %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ absolute_url }}" class="viewsitelink">
            {% trans "View on site" %}
        </a>
    </li>
{% endif %}
```

I have almost no customization here, so is there something wrong with how I reverse the URL ? What is causing the double HTTPS ?

Comment: Have you configured a `Site` using the `django.contrib.sites` framework, and if so, what `domain` did you specify there? That is the most likely source of your problem.

Comment: @solarissmoke I have `django.contrib.sites` installed with `SITE_ID = 1`, but no other settings. Should I specify something else ?